# How do I install lower version of angular material UI

Tags: angular, angular-material

I'm new to angular and I've downloaded an old project that uses this version.

> @angular/cli : 1.2.0

It does not show there what exactly the version of angular.... anyways, I tried running it but it gives me this error..

> File .../node_modules/@angular/material/index.d.ts' is not a module.

I figure that the problem was the `MdButtonModule`. What I found so far in hours of searching is that I need to change it to `MatWhateverComponentModule`. However, I think it's a lot of work and I decided to just use older version of Angular Material. 
But I just can't find older versions of angular material that matches the version of my angular.

Any idea? Thanks :)

Comment: The latest major angular version is 9. I suggest you update your entire project to the latest version

Comment: @PoulKruijt Isn't it a big work? Can't I just install a lower version of angular material instead?

Answer (score 1):

If you want a specific version, 1.4.1 for example:

```
npm uninstall -g @angular/cli
npm cache clean
npm install -g @angular/cli@1.4.1
```

Comment: I know this. My question is.... WHAT VERSION of ANGULAR MATERIAL should I USE that is compatible for the current version of my angular

Answer (score 0):

just set required version in **package.json** file without putting ^ mark for latest release[image] 
But depending of your material version you may need to downgrade other angular packages as well

Answer (score 0):

The angular cli version `1.2.0` is from Jun 29, 2017. Let me say it's madness to still try to work with this, mainly to find any relevant documentation or help for it. The material was even in beta at the time at version `2.0.0-beta.7`. For a proper application and development experience. I strongly advice you to update your cli to the latest version by using `npm i @angular/cli -g`, create a new project, and copy your `src` folder to the new `src` folder.

Answer (score 0):

`npm install --save @angular/material@8 --save-exact`.

`@angular/mentioned` here wich version do you want to downgrade.